# How can I test Twitter iOS 5 integration in simulator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter, ios-simulator

I don't have access to download the Twitter app in the simulator. Any idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to install the Twitter app in the simulator. That's a separate app by itself.

You should be able to test Twitter iOS 5 integration within your apps in the simulator after you authorize an account in the simulator's Settings app. You and your users are not required to install Twitter's official app in order to use any of the built-in features.

Comment: I wanted to test the single sign on, actually

Comment: @adit: I edited my answer. SSO should work as well as Tweet Sheets. As long as your app is picking up accounts authorized in the Settings app, SSO should be working fine.